# Stock Android 10 device is offline for ADB commands on Linux, can't use USB Debugging

Tags: adb, linux, stock-android, android-10, motorola

Trying to use `adb` tool `1.0.29` on a PC running Linux `Ubuntu 20.04` to debug my `Motorola Moto G7 Plus` running stock `Android 10` (hence not rooted) connected via USB.
Previously it was working OK, I've granted USB Debugging permissions to my PC. But today `adb devices` shows it as an `offline` device, so I can't do anything.

Here's a list of actions I tried:

- `Revoke USB Debugging Authorization` - it doesn't work, nothing happens, Android doesn't prompt for new permissions
- Delete `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` on the phone - Can't, no root, `adb root` and `adb shell` return `error: device offline`
- Rebooting, disabling USB Debugging and Developer Options and disconnecting in any order didn't help
- `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` didn't do the trick as well

What else could you recommend?

Comment: Was it working with that Linux version before? Because often we have here problems with Linux t!hat require to set specific permissions on Linux side so that ADB can access USB. Please search this site for details.

Comment: @Robert thank you for reply. Yes, it was actually working. At least partially. Device was active (not "offline"), and I was able to do some operations. I've not tested evereything though.

Comment: Are you sure the relevant adb key is located in `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`? From what I know I would have expected it to be located in the user directory, precise in `~/.android/adbkey` and `~/.android/adbkey.pub`.

Comment: @Robert Not sure. But in any File management app there's no `~/.android` folder. Internal storage does only contain visible folders, and `Show hidden folders` is enabled. When I create a folder like `.this`, it registers as hidden and is visible when hidden files are.

Comment: I was talking about your Linux system there you can find the path `~/.android/`.

Comment: @Robert Found it, deleted it, re-enabled `USB Debugging`, revoked auths on the phone. `adb devices` still returns my phone as `offline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by:

1. Deleting `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` files from `~/.android/` directory on my Linux PC.
2. Using newer Android Debug Bridge (in my case, it's current `1.0.41`/`30.0.4` from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)).

Also thanks to [Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert) for helpful comments.

---

## Update 2020-12-29

Another solution could be in using [ADB over Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236938)